# passing form data from one controller to another in angular

Tags: angularjs, cordova

```
.controller('CyclesController', function ($scope, $state) {
    $scope.age = 0;
    $scope.name = "";
    $scope.email = "";
    $scope.calculateByAge = function (age, name, email) {
        $scope.data = $scope.data || {};
        if (age > 0) {
            $scope.data.age = age;
            $scope.data.name = name;
            $scope.data.email = email;
            $state.go('tab.cycles-detail');
        }

    }

})

.controller('CyclesDetailController', function ($scope, $stateParams, CyclesService) {
    console.log('scope data', $scope.data); // <--- undefined.
})
```

This may be a dumb question, but can get to get the data from the form on the `CyclesDetailController` controller.

Answer (score 0):

If it's simple property you could do it by routing. Just change your "tab.cycles-detai' to 'tab.cycles-detai/:age' in your ui-router configuration and pass it when you're redirecting: $state.go('tab.cycles-detail', {age: age});

in 'CyclesDetailController' access it by $stateParams.age;

e.g:

```
//app.config
//...

    .state('tab.cycles-detail', {
                    url: "^detail/{age:int}",
                    controller: 'CyclesDetailController',
                    templateUrl: "url_for_detail_template"
                })

//...

// CyclesController

.controller('CyclesController', function ($scope, $state) {
    $scope.age = 0;
    $scope.calculateByAge = function (age) {
        $scope.data = $scope.data || {};
        if (age > 0) {
            $scope.data.age = age;
            $state.go('tab.cycles-detail', {age: age);
        }

    }
})

//CyclesDetailController

.controller('CyclesDetailController', function ($scope, $stateParams, CyclesService) {
    console.log('scope data', $stateParams.age);
})

//
```

Comment: I need more data. I simplified on the example

Comment: I edited my question, in your answer I need to include the url template with the params? isn't any way to not doing that?

Comment: I don' understand. It's only url for your html. You don't have any html related to CyclesDetailController ?

Comment: I talking specific about `url: "^detail/{age:int}",` why is age there?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data from one route to another but dont want to expose it in browser menu bar, you can use `squash`.

Example -

```
.state('app.enroll', {
    url: '/enroll/',
    params: {
        classId: {
            value: null,
            squash: true
        },
        className: {
            value: null,
            squash: true
        } 
    },
    title: 'Students Enrollment',
    templateUrl: helper.basepath('enroll.html')        
})
```

**2nd Technique -**

You can use **localStorage / cookies** to save data and retrieve at later stage.

**3rd Technique -**

You can always share data via **services/factory** in between controllers.